# Script to remove AD Computer and join them if not in AD

Tags: powershell

I am trying to fix a script that is used on an MDT server to remove AD computers of the same name then rejoin them. One of the parts of the script is to have a secure string that contains the password. I am getting these errors from PowerShell when the script is run during the re-imaging process.

```
Cannot bind parameter 'SecureString'. Cannot convert the "clear for security" value of type "System.String" to type "System.Security.SecureString". TaskSequencePSHost  1/28/2022 12:53:15 PM   0 (0x0000)
At \\LH-WDS-MDT\DeploymentShare$\Scripts\Swisd_scripts\MDT_JoinDomain.ps1:4 char:38
+ $Password = ConvertFrom-SecureString $SecureString
+                                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~    TaskSequencePSHost  1/28/2022 12:53:15 PM   0 (0x0000)
InvalidArgument: (:) [ConvertFrom-SecureString], ParameterBindingException  TaskSequencePSHost  1/28/2022 12:53:15 PM   0 (0x0000)
Exception calling ".ctor" with "2" argument(s): "Cannot process argument because the value of argument "password" is null. Change the value of argument "password" to a non-null value."    TaskSequencePSHost  1/28/2022 12:53:15 PM   0 (0x0000)
At \\LH-WDS-MDT\DeploymentShare$\Scripts\Swisd_scripts\MDT_JoinDomain.ps1:5 char:16
+ ... edentials = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential $Use ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ TaskSequencePSHost  1/28/2022 12:53:15 PM   0 (0x0000)
InvalidOperation: (:) [New-Object], MethodInvocationException   TaskSequencePSHost  1/28/2022 12:53:15 PM   0 (0x0000)
Cannot process argument transformation on parameter 'Credential'. The method or operation is not implemented.   TaskSequencePSHost  1/28/2022 12:53:15 PM   0 (0x0000)
At \\LH-WDS-MDT\DeploymentShare$\Scripts\Swisd_scripts\MDT_JoinDomain.ps1:7 char:46
+ Add-Computer -DomainName $Domain -Credential $Credentials
+                                              ~~~~~~~~~~~~ TaskSequencePSHost  1/28/2022 12:53:15 PM   0 (0x0000)
InvalidData: (:) [Add-Computer], ParameterBindingArgumentTransformationException    TaskSequencePSHost  1/28/2022 12:53:15 PM   0 (0x0000)
```

Here is the script that I am trying to run during the task sequence.

```
$UserName = "domain\user"
$Domain = "cleared for security"
$SecureString = cleared out for security
$Password = ConvertTo-SecureString $SecureString
$Credentials = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential $UserName,$Password
$CompName = $env:COMPUTERNAME

if(Get-ADComputer "$CompName")
{
  Remove-ADComputer -Identity "$CompName" -Credential $Credentials -Confirm:$false
  Add-Computer -DomainName $Domain -Credential $Credentials
}
else
{
  Add-Computer -DomainName $Domain -Credential $Credentials
}
```

Any help or a point in the right direction or a article that may help.

Thank you
Edited 01/31/2022

I changed the script like some one suggested. I am getting the following errors now.

```
The network name cannot be found.
    TaskSequencePSHost  1/31/2022 8:27:35 AM    0 (0x0000)
At \\server path\share\Scripts\****_scripts\MDT_JoinDomain.ps1:1 char:15
+ ... ecurecred = Import-CliXml -Path \\server path\share\Scripts\ ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ TaskSequencePSHost  1/31/2022 8:27:35 AM    0 (0x0000)
OpenError: (:) [Import-Clixml], IOException TaskSequencePSHost  1/31/2022 8:27:35 AM    0 (0x0000)
A constructor was not found. Cannot find an appropriate constructor for type System.Management.Automation.PSCredential. TaskSequencePSHost  1/31/2022 8:27:35 AM    0 (0x0000)
At \\server path\share\Scripts\****_scripts\MDT_JoinDomain.ps1MDT_JoinDomain.ps1:2 char:16
+ ... edentials = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential $sec ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ TaskSequencePSHost  1/31/2022 8:27:35 AM    0 (0x0000)
ObjectNotFound: (:) [New-Object], PSArgumentException   TaskSequencePSHost  1/31/2022 8:27:35 AM    0 (0x0000)
Unable to find a default server with Active Directory Web Services running. TaskSequencePSHost  1/31/2022 8:27:38 AM    0 (0x0000)
At \\server path\share\Scripts\****_scripts\MDT_JoinDomain.ps1 MDT_JoinDomain.ps1:5 char:4
+ if(Get-ADComputer "$CompName")
+    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ TaskSequencePSHost  1/31/2022 8:27:38 AM    0 (0x0000)
ResourceUnavailable: (LH-ADTEST:ADComputer) [Get-ADComputer], ADServerDownException TaskSequencePSHost  1/31/2022 8:27:38 AM    0 (0x0000)
```

The code is as follows.

```
$securecred = Import-CliXml -Path \\server\Share\Scripts\MDTCredential.xml
$Credentials = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential $securecred
$CompName = $env:COMPUTERNAME

if(Get-ADComputer "$CompName")
{
  Remove-ADComputer -Identity "$CompName" -Credential $Credentials -Confirm:$false
  Add-Computer -DomainName $Domain -Credential $Credentials
}
else
{
  Add-Computer -DomainName $Domain -Credential $Credentials
}
```

Comment: `ConvertTo-SecureString $SecureString -AsPlainText -Force`

Comment: By doing this would it make the password shown in the clear in logs? That is one of the things I am trying to avoid.

Comment: If you refer to what MS Docs states: "You should avoid using plain text strings in script or from the command line. The plain text can show up in event logs and command history logs." It should be pretty clear that what you want to do should be avoided. You should at least, generate a PSCredential object and export it to an Xml using `Export-CliXml`.

Comment: @TrevorRoney if the password is hardcoded in the script file then it's already getting logged

Comment: I changed part of the script to try and import an XML file like @SantiagoSquarzon suggested.  I getting the following errors.

Comment: If you exported a PSCredential object to XML when importing it, it will already be a PSCredential object (you don't need to use `New-Object .....` over it).

Comment: Thanks for the help I was able to get the script working.